# Facebook - Creating event gives "Uncaught OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred"

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the error "Uncaught OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred. thrown in /home/www/domain.com/public_html/includes/facebook/base_facebook.php" when trying to create an event under a page. This was working, and just seemed to quit without any real reason why but is working with other access tokens. I tried to reauthorize and get a new token, but its still getting this error. Is there a way to tell more of the error instead of "An unknown error has occurred"?

FYI, I can use https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token={access_token_here} and it loads the feeds or https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token={access_token_here} and read the events.

Array
(
    [access_token] => {access_token_here}
    [privacy_type] => OPEN
    [host] => Me
    [name] => test event
    [start_time] => 11/25/2011 00:00:00
    [location] => {name_of_location}
    [street] => {address}
    [city] => {city}
    [state] => OK
    [description] => This is just a test event
)

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add the venue parameter - see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/
That helped me when I had the same problem

Comment: Thanks for this, all the documents I had run across in the past listed to not put items into the venue parameter which has always worked. Thanks for pointing me into trying the venue parameter again.